# Set focus on the child control inside a panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, controls

I have a button inside a form which is itself inside a panel and that panel is also inside a panel. I want to set focus to that button as soon as the page loads. I have tried many different methods to achieve focus but unable to do so. Can anyone please guide me?

```
private void directionform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.ActiveControl = button1;
     button1.Focus();
     button1.Select();
 }
```

Comment: Handle the `Shown` event instead.

Comment: I have tried the shown event as well but no luck

Comment: Can the button and its containers be focused?

Comment: It should work by just calling the `.Select();` method unless some control is _stealing_ the focus (webbrowser for example). If no browser, use the debugger to find out in the `Shown` event which control is that. Also, call the `.Select();` method in the `Shown` event and press the Space key, does the `Click` event fire? Could be a visual problem. Try.

Comment: I have used the following code below to see which form and control is active .                   private void directionform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                                     
           MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm.Name.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name.ToString());
        } and the response is   form1 , then form2

Comment: `Form1` and `Form2` ? Now this is a different story. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).